# Providing resources files in Maven module

Tags: java, maven-3, m2eclipse

I am developing a new maven module and have some problems with resolving the dependencies. The goal is to create an maven object that provides my jar archive and a bunch of other resources. I created my pom.xml and installed the jar archive with install:install-file to the repository. That works's fine. But now I am struggling with the resources. Here is an example:

- pom.xml
- myJar.jar
- resources/resourceA
- resources/resourceB
- resources/...

The myJar archive is useless without the resources the they need to be deployed in one package. Can you please provide me an example or a hint which plugin I should use?

Comment: Kind of off topic, but why weren't the resources put into the jar file?

Comment: Where are your resources located? They should be in src/main/resources. You should follow this structure and then all resources are automatically included.

Comment: The jar archive is a proxy file and created based on the resources. Thus I need the resources files for the runtime execution. The location of the resource file is not strict and I can copy them to any location I want. The idea was to set the dependency to this maven module and resolve my compiler and runtime issues for my depending maven module ( and code)

Comment: I solved my issue. We now have a lib folder with all required resources and it works well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the maven assembly plugin. We can do the following:

```
 <project>
 [...]
 <build>
[...]
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <descriptors>
        <descriptor>src/assembly/jar_with_resources.xml</descriptor>
      </descriptors>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>make-assembly</id> <!-- this is used for inheritance merges -->
        <phase>package</phase> <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
        <goals>
          <goal>single</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
  [...]
</project>
```

You need to define the jar_with_resources.xml descriptor where you exactly say what is included in your assembly and what is not.

Comment: The file could be installed but ignored my resources. What is the correct build configuration here? In my case I don't have a src folder. The pom and the jar archive are in a new created folder with a subdirectory resources. All files are located in this subdirectory.

Comment: Have you already seen the maven assembly plugin. I think, it is what you need.

Comment: The comments here were right. My plan was too complicated. I introduced a lib folder and our maven infrastructure added it to my output. Thanks a lot helping.